# Convert c code to haskell code using recursion instead of loops (no lists)

Tags: loops, haskell, recursion, nested, counter

I want to convert the following c code to haskell code, without using lists. It returns the number of occurrences of two numbers for a given `n` , where `n` satisfies `n=(a*a)*(b*b*b)`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {

int n = 46656;
int i,j,counter=0,res=1;


int tr = sqrt(n);


for(i=1; i<=tr; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=tr; j++) {

                res = (i*i) * (j*j*j) ;
                if(res==n) {
            counter=counter+1;
        }
        printf("%d\n",res);
    }

}

printf("%d\n",counter);
}
```

I've managed to do something similar in haskell in regarding to loops, but only for finding the overall sum. I find difficult implementing the if part and counter part(see on c code) in haskell also. Any help much appreciated! Heres my haskell code also:

```
sumF :: (Int->Int)->Int->Int
sumF f 0 = 0
sumF f n = sumF f (n-1) + f n



sumF1n1n :: (Int->Int->Int)->Int->Int
sumF1n1n f 0 = 0
sumF1n1n f n = sumF1n1n f (n-1)
               +sumF (\i -> f i n) (n-1)
               +sumF (\j -> f n j) (n-1)
               +f n n

func :: Int->Int->Int
func 0 0 = 0
func a b = res
        where
        res = (a^2 * b^3)

call :: Int->Int
call n = sumF1n1n func n
```

Comment: You appear to have the same homework as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202475/the-number-of-the-product-n-a2-a3-using-recursion-only-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that it isn't possible, but definitely not the best looking:

```
counter n = go (sqrt n) (sqrt n)
    where
    go 0 _  = 0
    go i tr = (go2 tr 0 i) + (go (i - 1) tr)
    go2 0 c i = c
    go2 j c i = go2 (j - 1) (if i^2 * j^3 == n then c + 1 else c) i
```

Comment: I changed the sqrt to a custom sqrtInt function and it worked. You're a savior man , really thank you from the bottom of my heart!!!

Answer (score 4):

I guess an idiomatic translation would look like this:

```
n = 46656
tr = sqrt n
counter = length
    [ ()
    | i <- [1..tr]
    , j <- [1..tr]
    , i*i*j*j*j == n
    ]
```

Comment: Great answer , i also thought about finding the length of a list for the counter , but unfortunately i must implement it in haskell WITHOUT any usage of lists and imported code  :-(  . Only recursion left maybe? Like reinventing the wheel .

Comment: Who is telling you to do this without lists? Seems like a pointless exercise.

Comment: My captors :-(  sorry , haha

Answer (score 0):

A general and relatively straightforward way to translate imperative code is to replace each basic block with a function, and give it a parameter for every piece of state it uses. If it’s a loop, it will repeatedly tail-call itself with different values of those parameters. If you don’t care about printing the intermediate results, this translates straightforwardly:

The main program prints the result of the outer loop, which begins with `i` = 1 and `counter` = 0.

```
main = print (outer 1 0)
  where
```

These are constants, so we can just bind them outside the loops:

```
    n = 46656
    tr = floor (sqrt n)
```

The `outer` loop tail-calls itself with increasing `i`, and counter updated by the `inner` loop, until `i > tr`, then it returns the final counter.

```
    outer i counter
      | i <= tr = outer (i + 1) (inner 1 counter)
      | otherwise = counter
      where
```

The `inner` loop tail-calls itself with increasing `j`, and its `counter` (`counter'`) incremented when `i^2 * j^3 == n`, until `j > tr`, then it returns the updated counter back to `outer`. Note that this is inside the `where` clause of `outer` because it uses `i` to calculate `res`—you could alternatively make `i` an additional parameter.

```
        inner j counter'
          | j <= tr = inner (j + 1) $ let
            res = i ^ 2 * j ^ 3
            in if res == n then counter' + 1 else counter'
          | otherwise = counter'
```